# @PropertySource() is not working in bean defined in XML imported by @ImportResource()

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Can not find correct answer to next situation in Internet. So, if it was already discussed somewher, just point out.

I jave UnitTest that is run by Spring:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/app-core-config.xml")
public class ConcurrentProcessingTest extends AbstractLSTest {
  public void testMethod1(){
    ...
  }
}
```

`spring/app-core-config.xml` contains some beans that use `@PropertySource`.

For example, `Service1Impl`:

```
@Service    
@PropertySource("classpath:system/service1.properties")
public class Service1Impl {
    @Value("${event.ack.warning}")
    private String eventAckWarningComm;

    @Value("${event.ack.info}")
    private String eventAckInfoComm;
}
```

So, few classes with similar usage of `@PropertySource` are defined in `spring/app-core-config.xml`.

When I run mentioned UnitTest all works fine.

But I need some additional Java configuration for specific UnitTest.
So, I written next simple configuration for previous UnitTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConcurrentProcessingTest.AppCoreConfiguration.class})
public class ConcurrentProcessingTest extends AbstractLSTest {

  @Configuration
  @ImportResource("classpath:spring/app-core-config.xml")
  //@PropertySource("classpath:system/service1.properties")  -- if uncommented, UT works
  //But it is annoying to add all propery-files here
  static class AppCoreConfiguration { 
    //Here I want to add extra configuration in Java style
  }

  public void testMethod1(){
    ...
  }
}
```

But when I run this UnitTest, I get next exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'event.ack.warning' in string value "${event.ack.warning}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:871)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 184 more
```

Could someone explain me why `@PropertySource` is not working in bean defined in XML imported by `@ImportResource`  ?

Comment: `@PropertySource` will only work on beans annotated with `@Configuration` not some arbitrary other beans.

Comment: @M Hm.... but in pure XML configuration @PropertySource works for Beans(Services) wery well. Is it bug in @ImportResource()  related functionality ?

Comment: No it isn't, nor should it work for any other type of beans as the `PropertySource` is processed in the `ConfigurationClassParser` if anything I would consider defining and reading `@PropertySource` on anything but a `@Configuration` class is a bug. Having `@PropertySource` on anything else but a `@Configuration` class doesn't make sense as it is configuration related and not service or anything else related.

Comment: Hmm a little digging into the sources shows that `@Component` annotated beans are considered **lite** configuration beans (which makes sense as that is also explained in the documentation). So if your service is annotated with `@Service` it should in theory work.

Comment: @Deinum, Yes, my Service1Impl is annotated as `@Service`. So, it works in pure XML config, but does not in mixed Java/XML style.

Answer (score 0):

After you have demarcated your class with respective propertysource you need to declare static propertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer bean like below in your configuration class

```
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer xxxpropertyConfig() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```